# ExposeLocally failed with COM error

Tags: c++, volume-shadow-service

I am following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321273/VSS-API-IN-CPP) article to create a snapshot using Windows VSS service and further taking it a step ahead by mounting it.

After searching I found a method `ExposeSnapshot()`to which I passed the required parameter as below

`result = pBackup->ExposeSnapshot(snapshotProp.m_SnapshotId, NULL, VSS_VOLSNAP_ATTR_EXPOSED_LOCALLY, L"C:\\Mount\\", &pwszExposed);`

Also I set the context to `result = pBackup->SetContext(VSS_CTX_APP_ROLLBACK | VSS_CTX_BACKUP);` as only persistent shadow copies can be mounted locally still t have the same `HRESULT = 0x80070057` which reads as `One or more arguments are invalid`

What's the possible error here ?

PS: I have used `L"C:\\Mount\\` as well as `L"C:\Mount\\` but both does not seem to work

Comment: I tried it but the result is same @HansPassant

Comment: While debugging I found that the variable `pwszExposed` is not getting populated, ofcourse because the method is failing. I refered https://github.com/uri247/Win81Desktop/blob/master/VShadow%20Volume%20Shadow%20Copy%20Service%20sample/C%2B%2B/expose.cpp but it is using the method in same way as I am using.

Comment: Okay, It seems that there was some problem with the directory. It's working now I used the path as `L"C:\\Mount"`